# how to model sheet metal nailed to wood?

Tags: modeling

I was hoping someone can point me in the right direction on how to go about modeling sheet metal nailed to wood. what I am looking for is to make an impression around the head of the nail where it forces the metal to press into the wood like in the reference photo below. any help would be appreciated. I would prefer not to sculpt anything.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to give enough topology to your mesh so that you can bend it and create hollows:

[image]